# Происхождение слова "скандировать"

Tags: этимология

По сути, весь вопрос в заголовке: откуда пришло слово "скандировать" в русский язык?

Answer (score 2):

Для поиска ответов на подобные вопросы пользуйтесь [Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org).

[Скандировать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#:%7E:text=scandere%20%C2%AB%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%3B%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE,%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2.):

**Этимология**

Происходит от лат. [scandere](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/scando#%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) «восходить; достигать; размеренно читать» (восходит к праиндоевр. *skand- «прыгать, скакать»). Русск. **скандировать** заимств. через нем. [skandieren](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/skandieren#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).
*Использованы данные Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов (2007)*.

Comment: В Викисловаре много вольностей и неточностей, поэтому в который раз призываю пользоваться им с осторожностью и, при ссылке, например, на Фасмера, смотреть в Фасмера, но не на Викисловаре. (Просто заметка, тут, может быть, всё нормально со _скандировать_.)